# Core Data - can I store a calculated value as a persistent attribute?

Tags: cocoa, performance, core-data, fetch, transient

### Background

- I have a calculated value stored in a transient attribute.
- Every time my app starts up, the transient needs to be updated.
- Startup time is really slow (i.e. 10-15 seconds)
- Instruments confirms the update is very expensive.

### Question

Is it OK to store a calculated value in a persistent attribute?

I'd use [Martin Brugger's Dependant Properties](https://github.com/mbrugger/CoreDataDependentProperties) to keep the calculated value up to date.

### More Information

My calculated value is the duration on thousands of objects:

```
Name                       Duration
Users                      70s            
    Proposal.doc           35s   
      12:32-12:32          5s   
      13:11-13:11          30s   
    Proposal2.doc          35s   
      14:32-14:32          15s   
      15:11-15:11          20s   
    ...thousands more objects...
```

### What I've Tried

- I've minimised the number of faults that are firing, using prefetching and `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO` but it uses loads of memory and still takes ages.
- I've made my transient updating code as efficient as I know how.
- I know I could fetch on a background thread and use a progress bar, but I'd prefer the user to not have to wait at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but the simple answer to what I think you're asking is "of course." :-)

There's nothing wrong at all with having a transient, real-time computed "currentTotalDuration" value *and* a "cachedTotalDuration" attribute. When "currentTotalDuration" is updated, throw it into "cachedTotalDuration" and it's done. It sounds perfectly reasonable to me to have a persistent cached attribute alongside a "live-computed" transient value that's only used when it needs to be updated.

I'm not familiar with Martin Brugger's Dependant Properties, but it sounds like most of the hard work is already done for you.

I hope I answered the question you actually asked. :-D

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly quick answer, Joshua. You've got the gist of my original question. Why could I not ditch the transient "currentTotalDuration" altogether and just rely on "cachedTotalDuration"?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that since I'm not familiar with how your "recompute the totals" logic works. :-) Your post suggested you needed to use the attribute to recompute your values. If you have a separate "update" method that doesn't need to be an attribute, then you can do just that.

Comment: I do have a separate update method that updates the attribute. I was just asking in case having only "cachedTotalDuration" as a persistent attribute did something strange that would mess up my data store or crash my code. From what you say, it sounds safe to do this. Thanks for your speedy and excellent answer.

Comment: Sure. I suppose what's tripping me up is that, to me, "it's just another persistent attribute". What you use it for is entirely up to you. :-) Reading into the possible cause for your concern: your end users won't see your data model so even if it "feels dirty" to you, your users don't even know it's there, only that the app no longer takes 30 seconds to launch. :-D

Comment: Since I'm still new to a lot of core data stuff, I guess it's just me being paranoid. I'm now excited that I'll be able to get my app to load in less than 30 seconds. Preferably more like 2... :)

Comment: I assume from your profile this is for your timerless time tracker? If so I assume you have a funnel point to track changes to "watched" documents? If that's also true, the funnel point is the ideal place to do all this since you're already working on the document and its time entries at that point. You can batch-fault all its time entries in one go, sum them, store the total, and let CD clean stuff up as it will.

Comment: Yep, the question relates to that project. The design is a bit more complex than that, unfortunately. :( But thanks for going the extra mile to suggest an extra improvement! :) Thanks again.